# Why this highlight code not work correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf, regex, richtextbox

First than nothing I don't speak english, I'll try to explain my problem.

I'm making a chat control using XAML and C#, I made a custom Table control with 3 columns to add it directly in RichTextBox.Document.Blocks, all is right; I have a code for highlight text by regular expression but not working correctly highlighting others things but not the regex matches, here is the code:

```
    TextPointer start = message.content.ContentStart;
    foreach (var x in styles)
    {
        for (var y = Regex.Match(message.Content as string, x.Key); y.Success; y = y.NextMatch())
        {
            var textrange = new TextRange(
                start.GetPositionAtOffset(y.Index),
                start.GetPositionAtOffset(y.Index + y.Length));
            textrange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty,
                new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
        }
    }
```

message.content is a run in a paragraph, styles is a dictionary of string (regex) and a text style but isn't implemented for easy reading of it.

Thanks in advance and excuse my english :s

Comment: Does it highlight all things *aside* from the regex matches?

Comment: It highlight crazy things, I think the problem is the transformation from offset to TextPointer but I not been able to solve the problem...

Comment: The starting offset works for me, but the + y.Length doesn't create the proper TextRange - it is always 2-4 characters short.

Comment: Per the documentation GetPositionAtOffset's offset is in 'symbols' not printable characters. Hence using it with an index generated from the string doesn't work.